# python Beautifulsoup match element by string equal to tag or attribute key or attribute value

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I need code to matching text in element with regex, for example:
 to match phone in html element, but Sometimes the TYPE of the element is a phone or telephone, sometimes the TAG is a phone, sometimes the NAME, sometimes the CLASS and more, and sometimes the ATTRIBUTE itself is called a phone.

How do I perceive the element by querying:
 something like:

```
soup.findAll(re.compile("phone"), attrs=re.compile('phone'))
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could give the URL of where the HTML is, or the HTML itself if it can be cut down in size. Use the [edit] button to include it into your question.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I have not added HTML because I need SCRAPING on many sites.

Answer (score 1):

no need for re

```
res = soup.select("phone, #phone, .phone, [name='phone'], [phone!='']")
```

with css selectors `phone` matches tag phone, `#phone` id phone, `.phone` class name phone, `[name='phone']` catches an attribute "name" with value "phone" and `[phone!='']` an attribute "phone" with no empty value

Comment: thanks, but i need regex to get all attribute including "phone" (telephone or something like this. And I'm looking for something that will include all attributes type or anything else, without specifying id class type name, etc.